# ESXi 5.5 crashing under load

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have a whitebox dual CPU home server running ESXi 5.5.

I have loaded the server up with a bunch of VM's for learning Microsoft SCCM. I noticed that as soon as one of the guests gets under load, the host will crash with the attached photo (apologies for the quality). [image]Could this be due to a dying CPU? I have noticed that one of the CPU's runs quite a bit hotter than the other.

Comment: This is an off topic question. You may ask it at http://superuser.com/

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, you should seek help on Server Fault.

Comment: My apologies, closing off this question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with CPU overheating the machine would shut down first, however if the temperature inside the case is too hot, something else might be getting affected (e..g memory or video display circuitry).

If you want to diagnose overheating, I can suggest placing a vacuum cleaner hose over the air vent, this will draw much more air than your regular fans. If the system stays up under load with the vacuum cleaner attached, it will be an overheating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming issue, so I'll close this off and note the resolution I found incase anyone else has the same issue.

Looks like this was a known issue under ESXi 5.X that has to do with the E1000 and E1000e virtual network adapter as per the lines:

```
@BlueScreen: #PF Exception 14 in world wwww:WorldName IP 0xnnnnnnnn addr 0x0
PTEs:0xnnnnnnnn;0xnnnnnnnn;0x0;
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]E1000PollRxRing@vmkernel#nover+0xdb9
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]E1000DevRx@vmkernel#nover+0x18a
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]IOChain_Resume@vmkernel#nover+0x247
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]PortOutput@vmkernel#nover+0xe3
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]EtherswitchForwardLeafPortsQuick@#+0xd6
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]EtherswitchPortDispatch@#+0x13bb
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]Port_InputResume@vmkernel#nover+0x146
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]Port_Input_Committed@vmkernel#nover+0x29
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]E1000DevAsyncTx@vmkernel#nover+0x190
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]NetWorldletPerVMCB@vmkernel#nover+0xae
0xnnnnnnnn:[0xnnnnnnnn]WorldletProcessQueue@vmkernel#nover+0x486
```

Simply remove any adapters using E1000/e and replace with VMXNET3.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2059053